# why won't visual studio code run my code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

For example if I run in vs code the following:

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
for x in fruits:
  print(x)
```

what it shows in the terminal is:

```
for x in fruits:
...     print(x)
...
```

So the next thing I tried to do is run it line by line, but when I only run

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
```

It shows in the terminal

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't know what the reason is, and I know nothing about programming, but this is supposed to work I think. I use anaconda navigator, and for some reason jupyter notebook works flawless, but vs code is constantly throwing errors at whatever I do. And sometimes it suddenly works and actually runs a command. Anyone got an idea?

In jupyter notebook the output is:

```
apple
banana
cherry
```

Comment: Try this:
Ctl+Shift+P -> Run Python File In Terminal.     

If that doesn't work let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute the script. You can do this through the command palette by hitting `ctrl + shift + p` and then typing `python: Run file in terminal`. That will run the specific file that you're currently looking at within the window.

Comment: This throws another kind of error, but this also would run the entire file right? Can't I run a couple of lines with shift+enter?

Comment: Yes this runs the file. If you just want to run the selection, which maybe you do, you can select the code and hit `shift + enter`. If it doesn't run immediately just go down to the terminal and hit "enter" with your keyboard because it needs the additional line break.

Comment: "just go down to the terminal and hit "enter" with your keyboard because it needs the additional line break" Okay I'm dumb, this was just it, didn't even think about this, thanks! I hit enter and tada there was my apple
banana
cherry

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes I have the same problem.
Just run the code with the Command Prompt/Power Shell it is better anyways.
Navigate with "cd examplelocation" to your file Folder and then type in the programs name.

Example:

C:\Users\eirik>

cd desktop

C:\Users\eirik\Desktop>

cd python

C:\Users\eirik\Desktop\Python> (Folder were my program is stored)

example.py

Answer (score 0):

You can seperately run it in a terminal if you just want a solution
by typing

> python youscriptname.py

Right now you are not running the script in vs-code, You are just opening a python shell with that code